# Translation of tracking (as in following a trail)

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais

I have created an website for my upcoming walk on the GR10 in the South of France. In English I have called it the GR10 trail tracker. The app's goal is to locate the user on the trail and tell them the distance to the next stop.

I'm struggling with an appropriate translation into French because they doesn't appear to be an equivalent verb for tracker in French. My first thought was to use traqueur, but this seems to the name for a "Wellington boot".

Does, "Suivre le sentier de GR10" make sense in this context? Or can you give a better suggestion?

Link to the website https://www.gr-trail-tracker.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use the verb "se localiser", maybe the title of your page can be "Se localiser sur le sentier GR10". Another solution could be to use the same title in english and french. Most (not to say all) french speakers will understand "trail tracker". We often use these words like in "je vais faire un trail" or "ma montre connectée est un super tracker d'activité".

Comment: Personally I would leave the word "trail" in English, as it is a very commonly used word in French, especially among the trail community. So, something like "Se localiser sur le trail GR10", and "trail tracker" or "tracker de trail" for the app itself.
That's my humble opinion of course. :D

Comment: You confirm my idea that us french speakers can deal with the english words. I believe it's the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will keep the English title, but use "se localiser" when describing what the app does.

Answer (score 1):

Par assimilation à l'« action de déterminer les positions successives d'un corps en mouvement, à l'aide d'appareils émettant des signaux de détection », on peut s'inspirer des certains termes parmi *poursuite, suivi, localisation ou repérage* ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363303)), plus particulièrement les deux derniers, plus utiles parce qu'ils recoupent des notions employées ailleurs dans le [domaine](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26500890) et ne font pas directement appel à l'idée d'une autre personne faisant le suivi. Et je peux ainsi imaginer *repérage en (sentier de) grande randonnée 10 (GR 10)*, voire *repérage (en) GR 10* tout court. Pour un nom associé à une fonction (*GR10 trail tracker*) je préfère *repérage* ou *localisation* avec *outil/logiciel/système de* etc., à un verbe en emploi pronominal qui est par ailleurs parfois utile pour décrire comment on l'utilise, soit pour se familiariser avec/s'informer du trajet, identifier, trouver, repérer sa position et déterminer sa distance des lieux d'intérêt pendant la randonnée, voire consigner des données sur le parcours réalisé etc. On connaît l'emploi de *trail* (mais pour moi *faire de la trail* c'est uniquement avec un [VTT ou quad](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8874047)) ou *tracker*, mais on trouve que le français dispose de tous les outils pour exprimer ces réalités, que ce soit celle du *moniteur d'activité* ou celle de la *localisation* ou du *positionnement*. Traqueur c'est soit le [chasseur](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=tracker&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), soit c'est très spécialisé pour le [capteur](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529627) essentiellement. Enfin le mot *randonnée* semble directement abrégé dans [GR 10](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentier_de_grande_randonn%C3%A9e_10), un [*itinéraire balisé*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentier_de_grande_randonn%C3%A9e) de randonnée pédestre d'une longueur certaine...